# JFrame Selecting Multiple Objects

Tags: java, swing

I would like to know if the multiple selections function used in list, will be workable too in the object?

The example I found was working on the list as provided from the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691623/jlist-listselectionlistener-multiple-interval-selection-that-waits-for-cntrl-or

The current project I'm working on is to draw different shapes which is an object. After done drawing, I shall be able to select more than 1 object by holding the SHIFT key.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can not re-use the List-Selection-Model in a **simple** way - i really recommend to use your own implemention instead.

To do so you must add a KeyListener and a MouseListener on your Panel in order to check for Shift pressed or not.

```
private boolean isShiftDown = false;
KeyAdapter ka = new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT){
            isShiftDown=false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyPressed(e);
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT){
            isShiftDown=true;
        }
    }

};
```

use **your own** selection 'model' which will be a simple list (java.util.List)

```
private List<Shape> selectionList = new ArrayList();
MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mousePressed(e);
        Shape shape = findShapeAt(e.getX(), e.getY() ); //i guessed you had a methode like that
        if (shape != null){
            //check is your shift key is down
            if (isShiftDown){

                //add or remove on click
                if (selectionList.contains(shape) ){
                    selectionList.remove(shape);
                }else{
                    selectionList.add(shape);
                }
            }else{

                //if shift is NOT down, clear the list before adding
                selectionList.clear();
                selectionList.add(shape);
            }
        }

        //show the selection in your gui();
        updateSelection(); //that's your part - draw a nice border around all Shapes from the selectionList
    }

};
```

don't forget to add **both** keyListener(KeyAdapter) and MouseListener(MouseAdapter) to your panel...

### NOTE

i would really use the **ctrl-key** (KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) instead of the **shift-key** to add/remove shapes by single-mouse-klick...